# Xamarin UITableViewDelegate Scroll Event Not Fired

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

[Please note this is a duplicate of a forum question over at Xamarin Forums.](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57934/uitableviewsource-scrollviewdidscroll-not-called#latest)

I have a UITableView of which the source is set to a UITableViewSource sub class. I have multiple methods in use at the moment, amongst the obvious ones; NumberOfSections, GetCells, RowsInSection, RowsSelected etc.

This morning whilst implementing a refresh view at the top of the table I tried to implement the scrollViewDidScroll (Scroll()) method, however it is not being called when the table view scrolls. There is no exception being thrown, nor is it hitting the breakpoint - but there is an assertion failed which appears in the console occasionally when I scroll the table view (not every time though):
    Dec 18 12:50:02 iMac assertiond[26037]: assertion failed: 15B42 13C75: assertiond + 12188 [8CF1968D-3466-38B7-B225-3F6F5B64C552]: 0x1

The table view source is set in the ViewController like so:
    journeyTableView.Source = dts = new DashboardTableSource ();

And within the TableViewSource code is as follows:
    using Foundation;
    using System;
    using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
    using UIKit;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using CoreGraphics;
    using VideoToolbox;

```
namespace AppName
{
    public class DashboardTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        public const string CellIndentifer = "DriveCell";

        #region Refresh View Related
        public override void Scrolled (UIScrollView scrollView)
        {
//          Globals.refreshView.DidScroll ();
            Console.WriteLine ("TV Scrolled!");
        }
        #endregion

        public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {
            if(!dataLoaded)
            {
                var rect = new CGRect (0, 0, tableView.Bounds.Width, tableView.Bounds.Height);

                UIImageView iv = new UIImageView(tableView.Bounds);
                iv.Image = UIImage.FromBundle ("NoData");
                iv.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Center;

                tableView.BackgroundView = iv;

                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                UIView.Animate (0.5, ()=>{
                    if(tableView.BackgroundView != null){
                        tableView.BackgroundView.Alpha = 0.0f;
                        tableView.BackgroundView = null;
                    }
                });

                return 1;
            }

        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIndentifer) as DashboardTableCell ??
                       new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIndentifer) as DashboardTableCell;
            if (cell != null) {
                cell.SetupCell (dataLoaded, indexPath);
                return cell; 
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            if (!dataLoaded)
                return 0;
            else
                return obj.Count;
        }

        public override bool CanEditRow (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            var cell = tableView.CellAt (indexPath) as DashboardTableCell;
            cell.SetSelectedState (true, true);

            SelectedRow = indexPath.Row;
        }

        public override void RowDeselected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

There are no other events which are listening for a table view scroll within the application, so I cannot really understand as to why this event is not being fired. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to be fine except for one thing. The problem is in you `GetCell` method actually.

First of all I assume that `DashboardTableCell` is a subclass of `UITableVIewCell`. If that is the case, in this line 
`new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIndentifer) as DashboardTableCell` you are trying to cast base class to sub class which can (and in my testing did) return null. 
`as` operator returns null if cast was not successful instead of throwing exception

Quote from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cscsdfbt.aspx

> The as operator is like a cast operation. However, if the conversion isn't possible, as returns null instead of raising an exception.

And then if cell is null you return null. Returning null caused Assertion failure for me too.

So you could simply replace `UITableViewCell` with `DashboardTableCell` and remove `as` like that: `new DashboardTableCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIndentifer);`

but this way looks cleaner to me:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIndentifer) as DashboardTableCell;

    if (cell == null) {
         // Notice that we are creating an instance of DashboardTableCell
         // instead of UITableViewCell
         cell = new DashboardTableCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIndentifer);
    }
    // cell is definitely not null now. You can update and return
    cell.SetupCell (dataLoaded, indexPath);
    return cell;
}
```

If this won't solve your problem I will look into your code once again :)

Comment: Hi andrius, thanks for that - didn't realise I wasn't creating a new instance of my custom cell! Always good to get a second set of eyes!

Comment: I have changed the code so that it uses the constructor within the DashboardTableCell class which is: public DashboardTableCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, string ReuseIdentifier) : base(style, ReuseIdentifier)
  {
   base.Init ();
  }
However it crash's at runtime as there isn't an IntPtr argument, however upon looking there isn't a base constructor that takes 3 args (style, ident and IntPtr)?

Comment: In my case the exact same scenario works just fine. Can you provide some code of your DashboardTableCell. And is DashboardTableCell a subclass of UITableViewCell or some other class thats base class is UITableViewCell?

Comment: In the meantime you can try this: public DashboardTableCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) {}